# How to get a function type that omitted last argument

Tags: typescript

Is there a good way to automatically generate a type like below?

```
type Fn = (arg1: number, arg2: string, arg3: boolean) => void;
```

to

```
type Fn2 = (arg1: number, arg2: string) => void;
```

Ideally, a handy shortcut like below.

```
type Fn2 = OmitLastArg<Fn>
```

Comment: Just have the last argument optional to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was pretty sure that I could use the new typescript 3.0 spread operator to do this but they are only permitted at the end of a function

```
// DOES NOT WORK 
// Error: A rest parameter must be last in a parameter list.
type OmitLastArg<FnType> = FnType extends (...args: infer A, last: infer L) => infer R 
    ? (...args: A) => R
    : any
```

I ended up creating a bunch of tests to match the function signature and infer it's type. Not the prettiest way of doing this but the only one that worked for me.

```
// OK \o/
type OmitLastArg<FnType> = 
    FnType extends () => infer R 
      ? () => R : 
    FnType extends (last: infer L) => infer R 
      ? () => R : 
    FnType extends (a: infer A, last: infer L) => infer R 
      ? (a: A) => R : 
    FnType extends (a: infer A, b: infer B, last: infer L) => infer R 
      ? (a: A, b: B) => R : 
    FnType extends (a: infer A, b: infer B, c: infer C, last: infer L) => infer R 
      ? (a: A, b: B, c: C) => R : 
    FnType extends (a: infer A, b: infer B, c: infer C, d: infer D, last: infer L) => infer R 
      ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D) => R : 
    FnType extends (a: infer A, b: infer B, c: infer C, d: infer D, e: infer E, last: infer L) => infer R 
      ? (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E) => R : 
    any
```

Comment: There is a way to do this but it involves compiler unfriendly recursive type aliases and is discouraged. I would go with the version above for the time being.

Comment: Thanks, Clément! You helped me.