# Combine type guard signatures

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've followed the example explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52237897/6338059) to create an `Or` function which takes a number of type guards and returns a type guard for the union type. e.g.: `x is A + x is B => x is A | B`. However I'm not able to use the returned function as an argument to an `Array.filter`.

#### Definitions:

```js
type TypeGuard<A, B extends A> = (a: A) => a is B;
type GuardType<T> = T extends (o: any) => o is infer U ? U : never

class A { q: any }
class B { p: any }
declare function isA(x: any): x is A
declare function isB(x: any): x is B

function Or<T extends TypeGuard<any, any>>(guards: T[]): T extends TypeGuard<infer A, any> ? (a: A) => a is GuardType<T> : never;
function Or<T extends TypeGuard<any, any>>(guards: T[]) {
    return function (arg: T) {
        return guards.some(function (predicate) {
            predicate(arg);
        });
    }
}
```

#### Code example:

```js
let isAOrB = Or([isA, isB]); // inferred as ((a: any) => a is A) | ((a: any) => a is B)
let isOr_value = isAOrB({ q: 'a' }); // here isAOrB is inferred as (a: any) => a is A | B which is what I want
[{}].filter(isAOrB).forEach(x => { }); // here I expected x's type to be inferred as A | B because of the type guard, however filter's overload is the regular one, returning the same {}[] type as the source array
```

I know I can explicitly write a lambda expression as the `filter` argument to force the type inference:

```
[{}].filter((x): x is A | B => isAOrB(x)).forEach(x => { });
```

But this is exactly what I'd like to avoid.

#### The same problem with an And function combining type guards

I've used the `UnionToIntersection` construct shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/6338059) but cannot correctly type the `And` function, here's my attempt and the error I'm getting:

```js
function And<T extends TypeGuard<any, any>>(guards: T[]): T extends TypeGuard<infer A, any> ? (a: A) => a is UnionToIntersection<GuardType<T>> : never;
// the above gives error A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
  Type 'UnionToIntersection<GuardType<T>>' is not assignable to type 'A'.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'A'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that you are accidentally [distributing your conditional type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).  If `T` is a bare type parameter, then the conditional type `T extends Foo ? Bar : Baz` will end up breaking apart `T` into its union members, evaluating the conditional for each member, and unioning the results back together.  This gives you the undesirable `((a: any) => a is A) | ((a: any) => a is B)`.

The easiest way to turn off such distribution is to "clothe" the bare type parameter in a single-element tuple, like `[T] extends [Foo] ? Bar : Baz`:

```
function Or<T extends TypeGuard<any, any>>(guards: T[]): 
  [T] extends [TypeGuard<infer A, any>] ? (a: A) => a is GuardType<T> : never;
```

That should give you the behavior you are looking for:

```
[{}].filter(isAOrB).forEach(x => { }); // x is A | B
```

---

The same thing applies to your `And`, with the minor wrinkle that the compiler will not understand that `UnionToIntersection<...>` will be a valid narrowing for the type guard function, so you might want to wrap it in `Extract<>` like this:

```
declare function And<T extends TypeGuard<any, any>>(guards: T[]):
    [T] extends [TypeGuard<infer A, any>] ? 
    (a: A) => a is Extract<UnionToIntersection<GuardType<T>>, A> : never;

let isAAndB = And([isA, isB]); 
let isAnd_value = isAAndB({ q: 'a' }); 
[{}].filter(isAAndB).forEach(x => { }); // A & B
```

Looks good to me now.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEHECuBDATgEwDwEEA0UAQlBAB7AQB2GAzlDgHxQC8UAFCgFz0CULTKKAEs6hANwBYAFChIUZOgxxIWGE1YwS5KrXYB7bikog+zJnuF0hlAGYQ0UAKpQA-E6jdKEAG73p0gGMAGxQaOhwoAG8oAEdDYygAX0CQsKIoqDB4kCTpDAhg9GgbJEoA4CE9SkscNlJsnm5SS3o8gpC0YtLyyuqRQjqGppbCfykSsoqqqAB5NFUtCmo6ZURUTCwjEAIthgY2AHN12m4YAG0AXUbpKFuoM5gLxZ06B-gFDes7B3woXae3BxuDhTAIWh8lPBVExPD57JJxt0ptU5gsyEtdKsIZtjDtjHtDscaKdLnxIjc7p1gEg0NUJj1phw0AdTmSKXdKRBqbSoEdFDQAHQ0PQAWwgbHpyPYYE6GCEARQFDZUg5qruMogcoVFCZBx4CLVt0S+vZuSkySk0iCXJqc2IrDmbDOIl+-SuYigVptIjmAH1vCggkhoKwXXa2NE4lAAOQoaNJfWeqRnSKJC4CmxCIIUNBsMNoQg8DN6NAAURQAQAFnV+BljWNZNBHJRejA9ABJSg5mgFZFYRzqU1sZzol5-BKAgDW3EcoKg3j0QgwHigXl8aD4o+W7DY0+EtnsUHbc4XS74bnbK7X8LG+UKnSgkt69GoaO026xxxx23HIAJfMwYlYFJThTQeJ4t10N5IGxL5D1+f5XCTDkgV4WtBBEKBS3INAK2AfsWyqNtO27XteiwCFVmhBgCEYK84TQBEvWAGocGoe0XwwJ0XQIN1E2YmpqH9QNgxYVj2IjWJuFjeNjQ9aQUzTDMsxzPMaBwNiMELYsywratmjMOtEwAemM+goAAMiIMYgA)

Comment: Thanks a heap, the `Extract` trick is something I haven't seen yet.